# PHP Contact Page Works but Shows Value Code

Tags: php

I have a .php contact page that works and sends the information from the form to my email, but it also shows {value=""} in two places on my form.

[image]

Am I missing "

The code is as follows:

```
<?php

        <form method="post" action="#contact" role="form">
                  <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="col-md-9 form-group">
                          <label for="name">your name</label>
                              <span class="fieldSpan">
                              <input type="text" 
                              input pattern=".{5,}"  
                              required title="5 characters minimum"
                              name="name" 
                              id="input-field-name"
                              class="form-control"
                          >
                          value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>"
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


              <div class="form-inline">
              <div class="col-md-9 form-group">
                      <label for="email">your email address</label>
                      <span class="fieldSpan">
                      <input type="email" 
                          name="email" 
                          id="input-field-email"
                          input pattern=".{6,}"  
                          required title="6 characters minimum"
                          class="form-control"
                        >
                      value="<?php echo $_POST['email'];?>"
                  </div>
                </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here your error

```
id="input-field-name"
                          class="form-control"
                      >
                      value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>"
                </div>
```

you put value=".... after the closing > of the input

Answer (score 0):

Use code as follows.Input value always in tag

```
    <form method="post" action="#contact" role="form">
              <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="col-md-9 form-group">
                      <label for="name">your name</label>
                          <span class="fieldSpan">
                          <input type="text" 
                          input pattern=".{5,}"  
                          required title="5 characters minimum"
                          name="name" 
                          id="input-field-name"
                          class="form-control"
                          value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>"
                      >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


          <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="col-md-9 form-group">
                  <label for="email">your email address</label>
                  <span class="fieldSpan">
                  <input type="email" 
                      name="email" 
                      id="input-field-email"
                      input pattern=".{6,}"  
                      required title="6 characters minimum"
                      class="form-control"    
                      value="<?php echo $_POST['email'];?>"
                    >
              </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the extremely fast reply! I had a feeling that was it but when I played around with it, it failed. Of course it works now.  Feeling silly, but grateful!